# Statistics for new questions vs closes

Tags: discussion

Is there anyway to get statistics for new questions asked and close votes for any time period, in any increment e.g accumulative, or by week, month.

I think it would be interesting to see

- If there is a growth or decline in questions asked
- If there is a growth or decline in questions closed
- If there is a growth or decline in the ratio between them

For instance, i have no idea if there are more questions asked this year than the year before, or if more questions have been closed this year compared to the year before, or if there any trends/ratios there-of

Additionally, It would also be nice to see if the new COC, or the be nice push is having an impact. If more people are asking questions these days, or if there are just more questions that need to be closed.

Does any Jedi know how to query for this, or has it been done or asked before?

Comment: PostHistory is your friend [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)

Comment: @rene thanks for that, when I get home I'll see what i can spin up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Updated to include date pre 2014**

OK, this was a learning curve... However, using the below Query I was able to tease-out (what I guess) I was looking for.

```
SELECT Min(CONVERT(date,creationdate))            AS date, 
       Year(creationdate)           AS PostYear, 
       Datepart(week, creationdate) AS PostWeek, 
       Count(*)                     AS Created, 
       Count(deletiondate)          AS Deleted

FROM   postswithdeleted 
       Where creationdate >= '06/01/2014'
GROUP  BY Year(creationdate), 
          Datepart(week, creationdate) 
ORDER  BY postyear, 
          postweek
```

[**Full Query and Data found here**](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/915822)

---

## Results

So, for some reason the data before the July 2014 is sufficiently different, in turn I excluded them from the results. Maybe someone knows about what happened with pre 2014 data.

The results are based on the following

- The data is obtained from the `PostsWithDeleted` Table
- The Deleted posts are obtained by counting rows with non null `deletiondate`
- The Active posts are obtained by subtracting Deleted posts from the Row Count
- The Ratio is just Deleted / Active

[image]

- Red is Deleted Posts
- Green is Active Posts (ones that survived the gauntlet)
- The background area is the Ratio between them

[image]

- Red is the Accumulation of Deleted Posts
- Green is the Accumulation of Active Posts
- The Blue is the Accumulation Ratio between them

## Conclusion

Assuming I am counting the right fields in the right way, I was surprised by the results.

- Seemingly the post-per-week count is fairly static, I would have instinctively thought the weekly question count would be growing.
- Also, in early 2016 the post-count drops off slightly, maybe this is a real thing, or maybe there is something going on in the background with SO and cleaning up data.
- I kind of expected that there would be a higher ratio of deleted posts than in the past. This is just from my own assumption based on what I thought was a growing number of crap questions possibly due to more and more schools teaching programming. So yeah, Deletions have risen, but then they dropped as well. Is this the COC and Be Nice policy, i don't know.

But the elephant in the room is, I thought there would be more and more posts as time goes on, this is not that case. Does it mean SO is dying? I don't think so, I think as a knowledge base its doing exactly what it was designed to do. however those statistics would be found else where.

In summary, this was actually a pointless exercise, I have learnt absolutely nothing and I want my 2 hours back!

Comment: I've always thought it a very strange notion that if you're not growing then you're dying. What's wrong with a steady state?

Comment: @MichaelKay yeah i agree, i was surprised by the lack of growth, yet even if there are not more questions a week, the true usefulness of the site would be gauged by traffic and whether people are solving their problems

Comment: Not so sure what went wrong here.  You did throw away the data that could have shown a trend.  March 2014 was a pivotal moment for SO, that's when the spring straw broke the camel's back.  Before that SO was steadily growing, the heavily increased student load in the spring made a lot of professional programmers decide to stop contributing.  SO got its own meta 6 weeks later, two years too late to do anything about it.  2015 was pretty steady, 2016 was when the question volume started declining.  Been declining since, no change from the [welcoming] campaign.

Comment: Once you get 25K rep you can see the [site-analytics page](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics).

Comment: @HansPassant yeah the data preceding this looked unpredictable and i was reluctant to include it, i probably should include it for completeness

Comment: I think its important to take into account that as more questions are asked, less questions need to be asked as they may already be discoverable through google or searching on the site.

Comment: @yitzih you'd expect that to be a smooth transition, not to have a sharp inflection point.  The slowdown in 2016's been observed and debated before, but AFAIK there's not an answer or even an official theory on what happened then.